# Epicor10-Image.Save method

Tags: c#, erp, epicorerp

I am trying to build a customized window in Epicor 10.
I have added a picturebox and just try to open a picture(bmp) from a file and then with another button to save it somewhere else.
The problem is that in Customization Tools Dialog from Epicor 10, where I write the code when I compile I keep getting this error:

```
Error: CS1061 - line 258 (953) - 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no extension method 'Save' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 ** Compile Failed. **
```

Now, when I have copied the code, and re-created a windows form app with Visual Studio 2012, everything works just fine, no errors on compilation at all.

The code is quite simple:

```
private void epiButtonC6_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
    var fd = new SaveFileDialog();
        fd.Filter = "Bmp(*.Bmp)|*.bmp;| Jpg(*Jpg)|*.jpg;| Png(*Png)|*.png";
        fd.AddExtension = true;

        if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            switch (Path.GetExtension(fd.FileName).ToUpper())
            {
                case ".BMP":                        
                    epiPictureBoxC1.Image.Save(fd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;
                case ".JPG":
                    epiPictureBoxC1.Image.Save(fd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
                case ".PNG":
                    epiPictureBoxC1.Image.Save(fd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }       
}
```

Comment: What type is `epiPictureBoxC1.Image` in the project where it doesn't compile? I'm somehow confused (if this is the line where the error is) that the compiler thinks this is of type `object`. Does this need some additional reference to the `System.Drawing` assembly?

Comment: epiPictureBoxC1 is the name of the PictureBox.
Type: Ice.Lib.Framework.EpiPictureBox

Comment: I meant explicitly the `.Image` property on which `.Save()` is called which the compiler is complaining about, sorry.

Comment: Well, it is the same type as in VS2012 .cs file
Image.Save Method (String, ImageFormat), but what I dont get,is why the same piece of code works with VS and not with Epicor(it uses the same version of .net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EpiPictureBox is not derived from System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox. It is derived from Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraPictureBox.

The Image property on **System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox** is of type **System.Drawing.Image** where as the Image property of **Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraPictureBox** is a **System.Object**. This is why things are not behaving as you expect them to.

I was able to get a mockup working by using the following which will work as long as you are sure that whatever is assigned to proptery of epiPictureBoxC1.Image is indeed going to be able to be cast as a **System.Drawing.Image**

```
switch (Path.GetExtension(fd.FileName).ToUpper())
        {
            case ".BMP":                        
                ((System.Drawing.Image)epiPictureBoxC1.Image).Save(fd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                break;
            case ".JPG":
                ((System.Drawing.Image)epiPictureBoxC1.Image).Save(fd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                break;
            case ".PNG":
                ((System.Drawing.Image)epiPictureBoxC1.Image).Save(fd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```